# Django inner join on legacy table

Tags: django, django-models

I am newbie on Django and using it on legacy database, I would like to perform a very simple table joining.

```
Table1:Purchase
PurchaseId(PK)
SupplierId(FK)
Date

Table2:Supplier
SupplierId(PK)
Name
```

After using the SyncDB it created the

Model

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
purchaseid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column=u'PurchaseId')
supplierid = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, db_column=u'SupplierId')
date = models.DateTimeField(db_column=u'Date')

class Supplier(models.Model):
supplierid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column=u'SupplierId')
name = models.CharField(max_length=45, db_column=u'name', blank=True)
```

I would like to get a simple join result, according to other post I tried

View

```
def purchaseList(request):
    purchase_list = Purchase.objects.extra(tables=["Supplier"],
                                           where=["Purchase.supplierId = Supplier.supplierid"])
    return render_to_response('purchaseList.html', {'purchase_list': purchase_list})
```

Is it the right approach and how do I get Purchase.Date and Supplier.Name in a table report in template? I have tried googling for answer but I am unable to find any answer, I hope this is not a duplicated question. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to tell ORM to join by foreign key neither corresponding IDs. All you need is <strike>love</strike> select_related(), see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

query will looks like:

```
purchase_list = Purchase.objects.select_related().all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does it mean I can do {% for purchase in purchase_list %} and then {{ purchase.supplier.name}} in the template? I tried it but it's not print the supplier name. Many thanks!

Comment: The way you've named your fields, it should be `purchase.supplierid.name`. Might be better to change the field name to `supplier` (the underlying db column can stay as it is).

Comment: Oh yea!! Thanks Daniel, that's exactly the reason why it doesn't work!! Appreciate it!!